# saving in excel without formula's

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use the following code in my worksheet:

```
Sub savesheet2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Copy
ThisFile = Range("A1").Text
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "H:\PUS\Overhead\Planning&Control\Planning\Leveranciers core\bestellingen\" & ThisFile
ActiveSheet.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What I would like is that for the new saved workbook all formulas are saved as values, so no visible formula's in the cells.

I hope someone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Right after:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
```

include:

```
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple VBA code will Convert All Formula into Value & Save the Workbook.

```
Sub Saveasvalue()

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wsh.Cells.Copy
        wsh.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="YOUR PATH\" & YOURWorkbookName, FileFormat:= xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

**Or this can be use also,**

```
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        wsh.UsedRange.Value = wsh.UsedRange.Value
    Next
   ThisWorkbook.Save
```